# Why does ofstream::flush() return ostream?

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

I was trying to do:

```
std::ofstream outFile (fname, std::ios::binary);
//...
outFile.flush();
outFile.close();
```

which works fine. But when I try to combine the two lines since flush returns a reference:

```
outFile.flush().close();
```

It gives error saying:

```
error: ‘struct std::basic_ostream<char>’ has no member named ‘close’
```

Then I looked at the reference more carefully and found out it actually returns `ostream` instread of `ofstream`..

why is this the case? Is it a bug or designed?

Comment: Because `flush` here is a member function inherited from `ostream` and `ofstream` didn't implement its own `flush`.. However I think returning an `ofstream` is a better choice.

Comment: You shouldn't need to flush if you're closing anyway. That's part of what close does.

Comment: In addition to not flushing before closing, you can also consider not to explicitely close the ofstream. At least if the scope ends there, there won't be any difference (unless you want to reuse the same ofstream object with a different file).

Comment: @stefan agree on implicitly closing with scope; variables should be defined in the most minimal scope possible, also let the destructor do the work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design.

`ostream` is a class that encompasses writing a sequence to an associated *stream buffer*, which is an abstract class that is in charge of writing and reading to *something*. That something could be anything; a file, the console, a socket, etc.

`ofstream` is really just a convenience class that extends an `ostream` to 'automatically' use a type of stream buffer that writes to a file, called a `filebuf`. The only functions provided by `ofstream` are `open`, `is_open`, and `close`; these are really just an easy interface to the file-specific functionality of the underlying `filebuf` stream buffer object.

If you really wanted, you could create an `ostream` that does the exact same thing as an `ofstream`. It just requires more code and isn't as pretty or explicit.

```
std::filebuf f;
f.open(fname, std::ios::binary);

std::ostream os(&f);
os.write("Hello world!", 12);
os.flush();

// Error! close() isn't part of the streambuf interface, it's specific to
// files.
os.close();
```

Basically, `ofstream` doesn't actually do any sort of writing, so it doesn't implement functions like `flush` and `write`. All of the writing is done via the `ostream` class, which manipulates an underlying `streambuf` class, whose job it is to make sure the data reaches it's intended location (i.e. a file).